# Script powershell for know Mcafee agent Version and Protection Version

Tags: powershell

I will like know the versión of the agent of AV Mcafee and Endpoint , it's obvious that I do not have connection at ePo console.

I got this script:

```
$AgentVer = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("LocalMachine",$Computer).OpenSubKey('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\McAfee\AgentVersion').GetValue('AgentVersion')
$ProductVer = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',$Computer).OpenSubKey('HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\McAfee\SystemCore').GetValue('') 



      " $AgentVer   Agent version: $AgentVer
        $computer   Product version: $ProductVer
```

But when execute I obtain:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:2 char:1
+ $AgentVer = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("LocalMa ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:3 char:1
+ $ProductVer = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('Local ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

    Agent version: 
            10.1.1.1   Product version:
```

I don't know how follow, any can help me ?

A greeting and thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have already specified the registry hive `LocalMachine` in the `OpenRemoteBaseKey` call, so it should not be repeated in the argument of `OpenSubKey`. Also, you should only give subkey path to `OpenSubKey`, not the full name of the value. This should work:

```
$hklm = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("LocalMachine", $Computer)
$subkey = $hklm.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\McAfee")
$AgentVer = $subkey.GetValue("AgentVersion")
$ProductVer = $subkey.GetValue("SystemCore")
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you.

```
$AgentVersion = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\McAfee\Agent"
$ProductVersion = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\McAfee\SystemCore"

$AgentVersion.AgentVersion
$ProductVersion.System_Core_Version
```